# Probability that two cards will be higher than a third

Tags: probability, card-games

I'm currently creating a game for class. I know that the probability of one card being higher than another is $8$ out of $17$. What I'm trying to determine is the probability of the following:

> A player draws $2$ cards without replacement from a deck. What is the probability that at least one of them will be higher than a third, subsequently drawn, card?

Comment: What have you done so far on your three card problem? This would give us a better idea of your background and situation and help us tailor an answer to your specific problem.

Comment: So you draw two cards, and then a third one without replacement, and want the probability that one of the two cards is higher  than the third card?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг correct.

Comment: @IanMiller my primary focus to this point has been on the probability of one card being higher than the second, without replacement. That's where I got the 8 out of 17. I've attempted to expand to the 3 card situation, but I've not gotten far. It seems that of the 2 initial cards, the only card of importance would be the higher card, but I'm not quite sure how to incorporate that in. If I have any breakthroughs I will add them to the initial question.

Comment: At least one higher, or exactly one higher?

Comment: I'm guessing your deck isn't a normal deck if you are getting 8 out of 17. How many cards are there? Are there duplicate values?

Comment: I may have misunderstood the problem, are you assuming a standard deck of $52$ cards?   Drawing without replacement?  I was thinking about a more general context.

Comment: @JimmyR. At least one.

Comment: @IanMiller I got 8 out of 17 from the following: after the first card is drawn, there is a 3 out of 51 chance that the second card will be a duplicate. Therefore, there is a 48 out of 51 chance it will be unique, which reduces to 16 out of 17. The chance of it being greater is equal to the chance of it not being greater, so 8 out of 17 is the chance of it being greater.

Comment: Ah, that makes it clearer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @lulu yes, standard deck with no replacement. I'm attempting to create this problem myself so I may need to adjust some parameters if it's unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability is $\frac23$ if the values are unique, $\frac12$ if two are the same and $0$ if all three are the same.

The probability for the values to be unique is

$$\frac{13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot4^3}{52\cdot51\cdot50}=\frac{352}{425}\;.$$

The probability for exactly two values to be the same is

$$
\frac{13\cdot12\cdot4^2\cdot3\cdot3}{52\cdot51\cdot50}=\frac{72}{425}\;.
$$

Just to check that they add up to $1$, the probability for all three values to be the same is

$$
\frac{13\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}{52\cdot51\cdot50}=\frac1{425}\;.
$$

Thus the desired probability is

$$
\frac23\cdot\frac{352}{425}+\frac12\cdot\frac{72}{425}=\frac{812}{1275}\approx64\%\;.
$$

Comment: The problem when conditioning on the value of maximum being $k$ for $1\le k\le 13$ leads to problem. Indeed $P(X_3<\max\{X_1,X_2\})$ depends on whether the $\max$ is attained by both the first two or only by one of the first two cards. So, although it seems straightforward, it is not.   Contrary, conditioning on the cards having the same value or not (as you did) is a more fruitful :) approach here. +1

Comment: An exhaustive search of all 132,600 possible combinations agrees with this answer.